# Performance after multithreading is the same as sequential run

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I have a program which runs a function multiple times like this:

```
int main(){
    std::ifstream file(inFile);
    std::string input; 

    while(std::getline(file, input)){
         myFunction(input); 
    }


return 0; 
}

myFunction(std::string){
//some work 
}
```

I create a thread pool using boost to run the function on multiple threads because their behavior fits perfectly in terms of parallelization like this:

```
 int main(){
    std::ifstream file(inFile);
    std::string input; 
     /*Creating the thread pool and intializing the threads*/
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work_(io_service);
    boost::thread_group threads;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));


    while(std::getline(file, input)){
    io_service.post(boost::bind(&myFunction, input));

    }
    io_service.stop();
    threads.join_all();

return 0; 
}

myFunction(std::string){
//some work 
}
```

I have added only a snippet of the code for the main parts. I'm getting the correct output but this did not improve the performance at all! I'm getting the same exact running time as if run sequentially.

I'm suspecting that the jobs are not submitted correctly to the pool but how can I check that?

**UPDATE** 
I was able to investigate the multiple threads and check if the work is submitted correctly, it appears it does each thread has its own work but still the performance did not change.

Comment: *How* do you measure it ? Looks like overhead of creating threads and/or reading from file overcome the gains from parallelizm.

Comment: You mean the gain? I'm comparing the run time between the two methods .. How can check the memory overhead?

Comment: by the running time I meant the time taken by the while-loop only

Comment: So if you are measuring the time of while-loop it could be the reading from file that takes most of the time and your function is rather fast compared to reading. This can be the reason you don't see the difference in runtime.

Comment: Perhaps it is `getline` that takes most of the time? Or that `myFunction` gets inlined and runs faster when not using `boost::bind`?

Comment: Typically - reading from file with multiple threads, while using HDD, will be _slower_ than reading the same file sequentially (due to increased seek times in comparison to read times). I believe that I saw some questions like this on SO.

Comment: Unless `myFunction` does something substantial, the second program should be slightly slower than the first. (The time it takes to read the file is a hard limit.)

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych even though I reading from the file sequentially?

Comment: @molbdnilo both programs read from a file, so how come the second is slower?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am have a sequential read from a file it is not random,  so would that still be slower?

Comment: @user7631183 If `getline` takes longer than a "job", you're doing the same sequential work as in the first, but with the added job management overhead.

Comment: @molbdnilo got it, thanks!

Comment: as a test user7631183, try reading the entire file into an array, then process that whole array either sequentially or parallel. It will at least tell you more about the exact overheads in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading same file from multiple threads in synchronous manner (and it is because you're using std stream for that) has no sense, because all your file read calls will be serialized by the system (this is how system works with files).

Probably, if you utilize asynchronous file reading (like IO completion) it'll help you to gain performance (in case that your work performed takes much more time than reading a file).

However, keep in mind, in case when your useful work on processing contents you're reading from a file is comparable to the read operation you won't gain anything (but additional cost and complexity on managing threads, context switches and synchronization) because system will queue your IO requests and they will be executed in a serial manner (unless you're reading from multiple distinct physical drives).